# Get pair of numbers from list of numbers in Kotlin

Tags: list, numbers, kotlin, sequence

I have the following list:

`[-1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, 23, 24, 25]`

What I want is the below list:

`[Pair(2,5), Pair(9,11), Pair(23,25)]`

I could do this using iteration with temp variables like `start` and `end`. But I am looking for a transformation method on `List` like `map`, `filter`, etc. to get my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would define an operation that splits the original elements into continuous sub-ranges of numbers not including `-1`. This can be conveniently done with operations over `Sequence<T>`, such as `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`. The only tricky part is to create one iterator and use it for each item of the resutling sequence of ranges:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.split(separator: T): Sequence<List<T>> {
    val originalIterator by lazy { iterator() }
    val eachSequence = Sequence { originalIterator }
        .dropWhile { it == separator }
        .takeWhile { it != separator }
    return generateSequence { eachSequence.toList().takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } }
}
```

A convenience function to apply `split` to `List`a just as easily:

```
fun <T> List<T>.split(separator: T) = 
    asSequence().split(separator).toList()
```

Then just take first and last item of each of the resulting ranges:

```
fun <T> List<T>.splitToRanges(separator: T) = 
    split(separator).map { it.first() to it.last() }
```

Example:

```
val ints = listOf(-1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, 23, 24, 25)
println(ints.splitToRanges(-1)) // [(2, 5), (9, 11), (23, 25)]
```

Complete runnable example: [(link)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/pnvdc228n5igmviof6on0d8aqe/s5tnmvjrf3vpimr3cmbn5o25im)